# Avoid underlining the trailing space before line wrap in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, newline, chromium

The following snippet renders (assuming) correctly without trailing space underlined in Firefox 59, but in Chromium 65 the bogus space in the end of the line before the explicit line break is rendered:

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <a href="#">This is long link, <br />with a line break</a>
</div>
```

Screenshot from Chromium 65:

[image: chromium screenshot]

Screenshot from Firefox 59:

[image]

The obvious fix for this case is to remove the space in front of the line break, but it is unnatural.

Is not one of the rendering wrong? Is either of the behavior specified by HTML or CSS specification or is this really undefined?

**Edit 1**: The same behavior as in Firefox can be observed also in the IE, so it looks like the Chromium is the only one.

Comment: it's logic, a white space is considered in the underline

Comment: @TemaniAfif not in both browsers

Comment: I would say the one of firefox is wrong but the more intuitive one ... by the way, try to play with word-spacing values and see the difference

Comment: There will be a css property [text-decoration-skip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip) which will address this. Not at the moment though.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for pointer. It looks like the chrome developers already play with it somehow.

Comment: Are you adding that `<br />` to force it to wrap to demonstrate when a long line would automatically wrap? Or is the issue only when a break element is present?

Comment: @Anthony the br is mandatory here to see the effect, as you may notice we already other line break without br and there is no trailing space at the end

Comment: @Anthony The `<br />` is there from a real-world issue when I encountered this behavior. It is there to ensure the line wrap happens on this place and not a word earlier or later (which is not completely clear in this minimal reproducer). When the line break is not there, it works unified among browsers as visible in other lines -- the spaces are rendered (as visible when selecting more lines) but not underlined.

Comment: You could use `white-space: nowrap` for the link, and then wrap the part where the break is allowed in a `span` and use `white-space: normal` to force it to break on that spot. https://jsfiddle.net/37qwff8c/

Comment: But I agree it's screwy that it doesn't collapse trailing whitespace on forced line wrapping. I'd check other browsers and file a bug with chrome if they're the only ones that handle wrapping that way.

Comment: So in regards to decorating the trailing space, if you look at what gets rendered in firefox, it is actually `This is long link,` new line 
`with a line break`. So the issue isn't that Chrome is decorating the space while Firefox isn't, its that Firefox is removing the space completely, and Chrome isn't. Firefox isn't choosing not to decorate the space, it is choosing to not output the space at all, thus nothing needs to be decorated. So the question becomes "should Chrome being trimming space on forced line breaks like Firefox?"

Comment: And here's an awesomely geeky post on the CSS working group github on the behavior you are describing: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1997

Comment: @Anthony cool. Thanks for the links and investigation. Feel free to fill an answer from that since it is already enough for one :) I was hoping somebody already encountered this or similar issue but I was probably not able to find the correct words to find it since I don't work with that from day to day. From what I read is that the space should be removed and not formatted according to the specs.

Comment: http://crbug.com/40634 from 2010 (!) seems to be the report of this bug, although not so clearly apparent. Took me quite a while to dig it up. Great answer, @Anthony BTW!

Comment: @myf thank you for digging it up. I was quite sure that it had to be discussed somewhere, but was not able to find the correct keywords. This could be also a valuable answer so it will not get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't that Chrome is underlining the trailing space while Firefox isn't. The problem is that Chrome isn't removing the trailing space when wrapping the line (when the wrap originates from a hard `<br />` wrap). The space is underlined because it is there, which is inconsistent with how Chrome handles trailing spaces when auto-wrapping text.

The CSS specification on [handling trailing spaces on wrapped text](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-phase-2) states:

> 4.1.3. Phase II: Trimming and Positioning
>
> As each line is laid out,
>
> 1. A sequence of collapsible spaces at the beginning of a line is removed.
> 2. If the tab size is zero, tabs are not rendered. Otherwise, each tab is rendered as a horizontal shift that lines up the start edge of the next glyph with the next tab stop. Tab stops occur at points that are multiples of the tab size from the block’s starting content edge. The tab size is given by the tab-size property.
> 3. A sequence of collapsible spaces at the end of a line is removed.
> 4. If spaces or tabs at the end of a line are non-collapsible but have white-space set to pre-wrap the UA must either hang the white space or visually collapse the character advance widths of any overflowing spaces such that they don’t take up space in the line. However, if overflow-wrap is set to break-spaces, collapsing their advance width is not allowed, as this would prevent the preserved spaces from wrapping.

The CSS Working Group has [discussed the inconsistent handling of trailing white-space](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1997) on their github repo, specifically mentioning that Firefox's handling of trailing whitespace is the most ideal:

> And lastly there's the point that trailing spaces just look bad, and that having a space just inside the closing tag of an inline or before a `<br>` is a reasonably common unintentional markup pattern that shouldn't have a bad effect on rendering. The preserved trailing space becomes noticeable both when the inline is styled, as in the example given by @palemieux, and also when we chose text alignments other than start. This gives a real-world use case indicating a preference for Firefox's behavior.

From this discussion, the earlier mentioned [CSS spec has been updated](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/commit/0cd3a8b91509a5d552e2b0cda79077dd2464a766) (in the github repo, but not apparently published yet) to match the Firefox (Gecko) behavior. Specifically updating points 1 and 3 from above to :

> A sequence of collapsible spaces at the beginning of a line *(ignoring any intervening inline box boundaries)* is removed.
>
> A sequence of collapsible spaces at the end of a line *(ignoring any intervening inline box boundaries)* is removed.

Emphasis on changes added by me.

Answer (score 1):

If we check the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props) we can read this:

> Underlines, overlines, and line-throughs are applied only to text
>   (including **white space**, letter spacing, and word spacing): margins,
>   borders, and padding are skipped.

Comment: Thanks you for the link to the specification. We can assume that in the other occasions without explicit line break, the space translated to the line wrap and therefore is not underlined, but we can ask why this did not happened with the explicit newline and space character.

Comment: @Jakuje actually I don't know :) am also trying to understand, but since it behave differently on browser it's not easy to know which is right in order to investigate

Comment: Check out https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-phase-2 which has been updated (but not yet published, it seems) by https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/commit/0cd3a8b91509a5d552e2b0cda79077dd2464a766

Comment: @Anthony fell free to update the answer ;) I made it a wiki one so we can gather all the information to understand this issue ....you can also add your comment about how firefox is removing the white space